# Is there a way to compare a suggested edit with Rejected and Edited result?

Tags: discussion, revisions-list, rejected-edits

If a suggested edit is rejected and edited, the post history only shows the difference between original post and the end edit.

Is there a way to see how big an edit of the rejecting reviewer was compared to suggested edit?

Answer (score 4):

The best you can do in SQL is the difference in character length and number of words. There does exist [SOUNDEX and DIFFERENCE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43389034/beyond-soundex-difference-sql-server) but those are of limited to none value given the free-text nature of the fields we need to compare here.  If you want anything more fancy you have to download the results and process it with proper text-diff tools.

The following [SEDE Query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/877369) determines which suggested-edits got rejected and edited and then finds the corresponding posthistory record.

In the result set it shows difference in character count, length in words for both edits as well as links to the actual revision and the suggested-edit review. The users who rejected and edited is linked as well.

```sql
;with rev as (
    select row_number() over(partition by postid order by creationdate) revid
         , postid
         , revisionguid
    from (
        select distinct 
               postid
             , revisionguid
             , creationdate
        from posthistory
        where posthistorytypeid < 10
     ) as allrevs
)

select top 100 -- don't break SEDE by requesting too much
       abs(len(se.text) - len(ph.text))  [#chars diff]
     , (select count(*) from string_split(se.text, ' '))  [# words in suggested edit]
     , (select count(*) from string_split(ph.text, ' '))  [# words in final edit]
     , concat('site://revisions/', ph.postid , '/', rev.revid, '|revision') as [revision]
     , se.postid as [Post Link]
     , ph.userid as [User Link]
     , concat('site://review/suggested-edits/', rt.id, '|suggested edit') [review]
     , se.text
     , ph.text
from suggestededits se 
inner join suggestededitvotes sev 
        on sev.suggestededitid = se.id
inner join posthistory ph 
        on ph.postid = se.postid
inner join reviewtasks rt 
        on rt.suggestededitid = se.id  -- the review task for the suggestededit
inner join ReviewTaskResults rtr 
        on rtr.Id = rt.CompletedByReviewTaskId -- review outcome
inner join rev
        on rev.postid = ph.postid 
       and ph.revisionguid = rev.revisionguid
where sev.votetypeid =3                   -- reject
and   sev.userid = -1                     -- reject / edit or OP rejected
and   ph.posthistorytypeid = 5            -- edit body
and   ph.creationdate = sev.creationdate  -- exact dates is the right record
and   RejectionReasonId in (109 , 9)      -- reject and edit
and   se.text is not null                 -- suggested edit on body
order by abs(len(se.text) - len(ph.text)) desc
```

When run this is what the result set will look like:

[image: result set with diff counts and revisons]

The query is a bit demanding so I only fetch a top 100. This makes that the query still runs on Stack Overflow. Either add more restrictions to reduce the number of rows to process or enjoy less limitations on smaller sites.

Keep in mind SEDE is updated once a week on Sunday. If you're new to SEDE don't forget to have a go with the [awesome tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial)